# Why Redis is O(N) for lindex, lpop

Tags: redis

I am trying to get my head around why `lindex` is O(N)?

This is related to needing to delete an element from list by index, and realizing that Redis only allows you to remove by value. So lindex first and then lrem.

Neither is better than O(N).

I don't get how redis is built. I mean is the list a Map? How does it retain indexes, order? Is is a **LinkedList**? Head, tail seems to suggest it is.

Also, none of the methods appear to be better than O(N).

Why do we not have lrem by index. Why only by value?

Comment: This link explains it very well how redis lists are implemented and what are the advantages/downsides; https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#redis-lists

Comment: @Ersoy, yes as I suspected, LinkedList. However, i believe ordo for Array like lists are pretty good as well. The only issue they'd have is to resize, which if you only intend to resize by one, is nothing. In fact, an implementation of a LinkedList could be based on an array based list and still perform just as well as this version. The problem now is we have o(1) for inserting removing, but nothing else. F*** this. The suggestin is to use sets? Really? That's just partially better, not by much. An ordered list based on a hashmap could probably be implemented. But this sucks pretty bad.